# removeSpan(styleSpans[i]) remove the previous style from the styled text

Tags: java, android

I am trying to remove the bold text from the selected text but when I hit the button it unbolds all the text which I bolded previously. It seems that removeSpan.styleSpan[i] not taking care of what part of the text I selected instead it removes the bold text from the whole bolded span string.

i want the selected part to be unbold only as shown
[image]

but after hitting the button for remove span it unbolds the whole line like this
[image]

here is my code i am using for it under one button

```
 private void boldText(){
  int selectionStartb = texto.getSelectionStart();
  int selectionEndb = texto.getSelectionEnd();

  if (selectionStartb > selectionEndb) {
      int temp = selectionEndb;
      selectionEndb = selectionStartb;
      selectionStartb = temp;
  }
  if (selectionEndb > selectionStartb) {
      Spannable str = texto.getText();
      boolean BL = false;
      StyleSpan[] styleSpans;
      styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStartb, selectionEndb, StyleSpan.class);
      // If the selected text-part already has BOLD style on it, then
      // we need to disable it
      for (int i = 0; i < styleSpans.length; i++) {
          if (styleSpans[i].getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD) {
              str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
              BL = true;
          }
      }
      // Else we set BOLD style on it
      if (!BL) {
          str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), selectionStartb, selectionEndb,
                  Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

      }
        texto.setSelection(selectionStartb, selectionEndb);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You're working with this text:

> ```
> Spannable str = texto.getText();
> ```

And you're searching for spans within the selected range:

> ```
> styleSpans = str.getSpans(selectionStartb, selectionEndb, StyleSpan.class);
> ```

It's important to understand what's happening here. You are *not* getting all the "spanned text", or even all the `StyleSpan`s, inside the selection; you are getting all the `StyleSpan`s applied to the **entire** text, as long as at least part of them is applied to the selected range.

In other words, even if you've selected only a portion of the spanned text, the `StyleSpan` object still represents the entire spanned text.

You will have to modify your code to handle all the different possible scenarios:

- The selected range has no spans on it -> add a span for the selected range
- The selected range exactly matches a single span -> remove that span
- The selected range is entirely spanned, but doesn't cover the whole span -> remove the existing span and re-add a span to the range that was previously spanned but not selected
- The selected range is only partially spanned, and covers the whole span -> remove the existing span and add a span for the selected range
- The selected range is only partially spanned, but doesn't cover the whole span -> remove the existing span and add a span for the selected range + the range that was previously spanned but not selected

Comment: Thank you so much for the detail. If you can tell me with the code i will better understand what you want to say. Thanks once again for your time. I will really appreciate that.

Comment: Too much bla-bla-bla... But no solution.... 
I have the same issue. Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is still actual

Instead of this line:

```
str.removeSpan(styleSpans[i]);
```

Try to use something like these lines:

```
   StyleSpan styleSpan = styleSpans[i]       
   // Get start and end of current span (not current selection)
   int spanStart = str.getSpanStart(styleSpan);
   int spanEnd = str.getSpanEnd(styleSpan);
   // Remove span which contains current selection (This is your code line)... 
   str.removeSpan(styleSpan); 
   // Check if current selection is not the same as current span object
   if (selStart!= spanStart || selEnd != spanEnd){
      // Create new span object before! current selection
      if (selStart - 1 > spanStart && selStart - 1 >= 0){
         str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
            spanStart,
            selStart - 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
      }
      // Create new span object after! current selection
      if (spanEnd > selEnd + 1 && selEnd + 1 < str.length()){
         str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
            selEnd + 1,
            spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
      }
   }
```